# I want to send notifications to the user when ever they receive a new item

Tags: python, postgresql, flutter, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using flask, flutter, and Postgres, and I want to notify the users whenever they receive a new item from someone, how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Push notifications use the firebase messaging service

To send a push notification to the user who has received a new item
for that integrate firebase messaging to your backend to send push notification on an event.

integrate push notifications in flutter using the firebase messaging service to receive notifications on mobile.

Flutter reference link
https://medium.com/comerge/implementing-push-notifications-in-flutter-apps-aef98451e8f1